# Turn off greetings/welcome from the Google Assistant

Tags: actions-on-google

Good day,

In addition to the normal explicit invocation, I also have implicit invocation in my Dialogflow project. If I start the app normally now comes first: "Okay, I'll start your trial." and then my default.welcome.

But if I now start the app via an implicit invocation, so "Ok Google, talk to my test App and Intent" is also the first greeting from Google: "Okay, I'll start your trial." and then my intent.

Is it possible to disable Google's greeting on implicit invocation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point - no, it isn't. The transition is intentional so users realize they aren't talking to the Assistant anymore but are talking to your Action instead.

However, it is a frequent request to streamline the startup in various ways or cases. We may see changes along these lines in the future, but Google hasn't announced anything.